# Classes for reading data from Sql Server into objects

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

The following is a set of classes that read metadata from Sql Server tables and populates local objects. It works, but I feel like there's too much duplication happening and too many places changes need to be made if something changes.

On the database side, the relevant metadata is collected into 4 tables with an additional `Description` column (I should not that I'm not able to use extended properties to store the description field and just read directly from the `sys` tables, hence the separate table approach). I won't list those in detail here, but the `TableData` class shown below mirrors the structure.

Firstly, there are 4 classes to represent a single record in each of the 4 tables, `DatabaseData`, `TableData`, `Schema Data` and `ColumnData.` I'll only list the code for `TableData` here, the others are structured in the same way (just with the relevant members and constructor arguments):

```
public class TableData
{
    public readonly int DatabaseID;
    public readonly int SchemaID;
    public readonly int TableID;
    public readonly string TableName;
    public readonly DateTime CreatedDate;
    public readonly DateTime ModifiedDate;
    public readonly string Description;

    public TableData(int DatabaseID, int SchemaID, int TableID, string TableName, DateTime CreatedDate, DateTime ModifiedDate, string Description)
    {
        this.DatabaseID = DatabaseID;
        this.SchemaID = SchemaID;
        this.TableID = TableID;
        this.TableName = TableName;
        this.CreatedDate = CreatedDate;
        this.ModifiedDate = ModifiedDate;
        this.Description = Description;
    }
}
```

These objects can be constructed through the `DataBuilder` static class. I'm not entirely convinced this is worth anything at the moment since it's not currently adding any additional value versus constructing the objects directly:

```
public static class DataBuilder
{
    public static TableData CreateTableData(int DatabaseID, int SchemaID, int TableID, string Name, DateTime CreatedDate, DateTime ModifiedDate, string Description)
    {
        return new TableData(DatabaseID, SchemaID, TableID, Name, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, Description);
    }

    // ... equivalent builders for ColumnData, SchemaData, DatabaseData
}
```

The main attraction here is the `DataFetcher` classes, which do the actual work of getting data from the server and creating collections of `ColumnData`/`TableData`/etc objects. There are a few different ways data will be fetched, so I wrote an abstract class `SqlDataFetcher` for the common functionality:

```
public abstract class SqlDataFetcher
{
    public readonly string ConnectionString;

    public SqlDataFetcher(string ConnectionString) {
        this.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    }

    public abstract HashSet<DatabaseData> GetDatabases();
    public abstract HashSet<SchemaData> GetSchemas(DatabaseData Database);
    public abstract HashSet<TableData> GetTables(DatabaseData database, SchemaData schema);
    public abstract HashSet<ColumnData> GetColumns(DatabaseData database, SchemaData schema, TableData table);

    protected DataTable GetData(string database, string commandText)
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            connection.ChangeDatabase(database);

            data.Load((
                new SqlCommand()
                {
                    Connection = connection,
                    CommandText = commandText,
                    CommandTimeout = 10
                }).ExecuteReader());

            connection.Close();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

The first concrete implementation of `SqlDataFetcher` reads data from the metadata tables:

```
public class MetadataFetcher : SqlDataFetcher
{

    public MetadataFetcher(string ConnectionString) : base(ConnectionString) { }

    public override HashSet<DatabaseData> GetDatabases()
    {
        HashSet<DatabaseData> databases = new HashSet<DatabaseData>();
        DataTable data = this.GetData(
            "DataDictionary", 
            "select DatabaseID, Name, Collation, CreatedDate, Description from dbo.DatabaseData"
            );

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            databases.Add(DataBuilder.CreateDatabaseData(
                row.Field<Int32>("DatabaseID"),
                row.Field<String>("Name"),
                row.Field<String>("Collation"),
                row.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate"),
                row.Field<String>("Description")
                ));
        }

        return databases;
    }

    // same logic for these ...
    public override HashSet<SchemaData> GetSchemas(DatabaseData Database) ...
    public override HashSet<TableData> GetTables(DatabaseData database, SchemaData schema) ...
    public override HashSet<ColumnData> GetColumns(DatabaseData database, SchemaData schema, TableData table) ...

}
```

Finally, the various `SqlDataFetcher`s (there will be others - one that reads directly from the `sys` tables, for eg) can be constructed via methods the `SqlDataFetcherBuilder` static class, with variants provided for connecting via either Trusted Connection or UserID/Password:

```
public static class SqlDataFetcherBuilder
{
    // Creates a new MetadataFetcher object. Uses Integrated Security (Trusted Connection) to connect.
    public static MetadataFetcher CreateMetadataFetcher(string Server, string Database)
    {
        return new MetadataFetcher(BuildConnectionString(Server, Database));
    }

    // Creates a new MetadataFetcher object. Uses a username and password to connect.
    public static SysDataFetcher CreateMetadataFetcher(string Server, string Database, string UserID, string Password)
    {    
        return new MetadataFetcher(BuildConnectionString(Server, Database, UserID, Password));
    }

    // Builds a connection string from Server and Database.
    private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder BuildConnectionString(string Server, string Database)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionString.Add("Server", Server);
        connectionString.Add("Database", Database);
        connectionString.Add("Trusted_Connection", "Yes");

        return connectionString;
    }

    // Builds a connection string from Server, Database, User ID and Password.
    private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder BuildConnectionString(string Server, string Database, string UserID, string Password)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionString.Add("Server", Server);
        connectionString.Add("Database", Database);
        connectionString.Add("User ID", UserID);
        connectionString.Add("Password", Password);

        return connectionString;
    }
}
```

---

**Known / suspected issues**

- As mentioned at the start, feels like a lot of common factors. If I add/rename/remove a column in one of my tables on Sql Server, there's currently 7 places I'd need to update the code
- Queries hard-coded in (actually, this is just temporary, with the intent to change them to stored procedures / views on the server)
- Not sure where the value is in the DataBuilder class
- Absolutely no exception handling at the moment

Also note, all my code *is* documented, but I stripped them out here to keep the question *relatively* short.

How can I improve this?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the wheel here for a particular reason? .NET has some very good built-in mapping between SQL and objects, any reason why you're not using them?

Comment: @Snowbody Asides it being the first time I've used C# in anger and am still getting to grips with what's available (being from a VBA background *shudder*, I'm used to needing to roll my own for this kind of thing), not really. Definitely going to look into Entity Framework.

Comment: It's definitely worth it. Also note that there's no technical reason for you to be stuck with C#. You can use VB.NET which, although not exactly VBA, has a very similar syntax. VB.NET modules are full-fledged .NET modules and can "speak" to C# modules with no translation necessary.

Comment: I know, I prefer C# though. I have an overall knowledge of other languages like C#, Java etc having done very small hobby projects at home and binge-reading various blogs and SEs, but this is the first time I'm using it in my actual job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> public readonly int DatabaseID;
> public readonly int SchemaID;
> public readonly int TableID;
> public readonly string TableName;
> public readonly DateTime CreatedDate;
> public readonly DateTime ModifiedDate;
> public readonly string Description;
> ```

I like that they're `readonly`. Very very much. But fields should not be public - these should be *properties*; you could write them as public auto-properties with a private setter, like so:

```
public int DatabaseID { get; private set; }
public int SchemaID { get; private set; }
public int TableID { get; private set; }
//...
```

---

Your *builder* classes feel like *static helpers* with mixed concerns, and seem to confuse the terms *builder* and *factory* - two creational patterns that differ in several ways; I invite you to read up on them both, and to look into the *abstract factory* pattern to unlock the usefulness and power of factories - because I don't quite see the use for the `DataBuilder` (and `SqlDataFetcherBuilder` for that matter) either.

The `SqlDataFetcherBuilder` class has mixed concerns and is doing more than what its name suggests, and leaves me wondering why connection strings aren't just stored in application settings, under a `<ConnectionStrings>` section.

The `SqlDataFetcher` abstract class smells, particularly the `abstract` members: I don't see what class other than `MetadataFetcher` will need to implement these abstract methods.

I don't mean to be harsh, but the whole code looks over-engineered with good intentions, but you seem to have written factories and abstractions *for the sake of writing them* more than for solving an actual problem: all the `static`-ness is only moving the object instantiation outside of your other classes, without buying you anything to help testability or, as you've noted, maintainability:

> *If I add/rename/remove a column in one of my tables on Sql Server, there's currently 7 places I'd need to update the code*

The main problem is that your code looks like it was written for .net 2.0 - if you can use LINQ to SQL, or better, Entity Framework, most of that boilerplate could be simply removed - you would only have a class for each of your *entities*, and then a `DbContext` implementation... and your queries could be written like this:

```
using (var context = new MetadataDbContext(connectionString))
{
    return context.DatabaseDatas.ToList();
}
```

Where `DatabaseDatas` maps to a table of the same name, with rows mapped to an entity type called `DatabaseData`, which is the only place you'd have to go and modify something if the mapped SQL Server table ever needs to change. No more magic strings and flaky `row.Field<T>("column")` calls!